# Python list comprehension logic error

Tags: python, regex, logic

I'm trying to weed out strings that contains `"msi"` using regular expressions and a list comprehension. However, when I print the list, strings that contain `"msi"` are still in the list. What exactly would the error be? This is my code:

```
spam_list = [l for l in spam_list if not re.match("msi", l)]
```

Comment: it's a good idea not to use `list` as a variable name as it shadows the builtin

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`re.match()` matches from the beginning of the string. Use `re.search()`, or even better, `in`.

```
L = [l for l in L if "msi" not in l]
```

Comment: Good suggestion of using python's in operator instead of overcomplicating the matter.

Comment: This doesn't allow me to weed out by file type; I'll have to interchange various or's if I do it this way. Using a regex allows me to easily specify (ie (msi|exe|jpg) etc)

Comment: @nobody: No one is telling you to not use a regex, if it's the appropriate tool.

Comment: @nobody, nothing in the question indicates that you were looking for file extensions. Be careful not to filter files that have msi as part of the name

Comment: @nobody If you are looking only for the file's extension, perhaps using `r".*\.(msi|exe||jgp)"` would be safer.

Answer (score 5):

Since you're apparently looking through a list of filenames, you could also use endswith:

```
list = [l for l in list if l.endswith('.msi')]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way to filter a list by the file extension

```
import os
extensions = set(['.msi', '.jpg', '.exe'])
L = [l for l in L if os.path.splitext(l)[1] not in extensions]
```

Comment: Or, assuming a reasonably recent Python version: `extensions = {'.msi', '.jpg', '.exe'}`

Comment: @Tim, set literals are in 2.7 or higher

Comment: I know; 2.7 just celebrated its first birthday two days ago, so I think that counts as "reasonably recent", doesn't it?

Comment: @Tim, sure, I just think it's handy to have the actual version numbers there sometimes